# is there are any ways to merge pdf docs into one pdf file(this file should consists from one pdf page as well)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have several pdf docs for example 4, and I need merge them into 1 pdf file. I was trying to use merge-pdf but documentation for this package is lean, so I got my merged pdf's but it merged into several pages. I should probably use hummus.js or another package, but I'm not sure. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on any computer using a free online PDF merger called PDF Joiner, or you can use a free app called PDF Creator on Windows or the built-in Preview program on Mac.

or **you can convert it by yourself by using copying content of all pdfs into doc file and save this doc file as pdf**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HummusJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hummus) for this purpose, here's an example of combining three PDF files. One might want to improve error handling / corner cases etc. but this certainly does the job.

```
const fs = require("fs")
const hummus = require("hummus");
const memoryStreams = require("memory-streams");

// Combine PDF files into one buffer.
function combinePDFs(...filePaths) {

    const pdfBuffers = filePaths.map(filePath => fs.readFileSync(filePath));
    const resultStream = new memoryStreams.WritableStream();
    const writer = hummus.createWriterToModify(new hummus.PDFRStreamForBuffer(pdfBuffers[0]), new hummus.PDFStreamForResponse(resultStream));

    // Add the subsequent files
    pdfBuffers.slice(1).forEach(buffer => {
        writer.appendPDFPagesFromPDF(new hummus.PDFRStreamForBuffer(buffer));
    });

    writer.end();
    resultStream.end();
    return resultStream.toBuffer();
};

const resultBuffer = combinePDFs("pdf1.pdf", "pdf2.pdf", "pdf3.pdf");
fs.writeFileSync("result.pdf", resultBuffer);
```

Comment: great, but i need that output was single page pdf, now it is not single it is pdf file which contains all my pdf files I want to merge